# Iterate over different collection types in a class

Tags: c++, iterator

```
class MyClass {
    std::vector<int> vi;
    std::vector<string> vs; 
}
```

I'd like to iterate over all the collections in `MyClass`with a single iterator, i.e., iterate through all of vi, and then through all of vs. `vs` and `vi` don't have a 1:1 relationship (so i can't use a tuple based iteration approach). This was a programming question I came across.

The Iterator design pattern works on collections of the same type, abstracting the access from the internal representation. Its interface is a useful thing to emulate for this problem, but the type difference between the collections is what's giving me a hard time.

I like to approach the problem from the usage perspective.

```
MyClass mc; 
... // push elements into mc
for( MyClassIterator   it = mc.begin();
                       it != mc.end();
                       it++)
{
   // *it can be either an int or a string
   // operator * for the iterator cannot return a common type! :(
}
```

I'm not even sure how to think about the design for MyClassIterator because of the different types in the collections (int, string in the example).

Edit: Just to clarify, this was an programming question I came across. I couldn't come up with anything sensible/elegant, and hence I'm asking it here on SO.

Comment: It was a question I came across, and I couldn't figure out a general purpose solution to it. Just wanted to check with the experts.

Comment: Before you worry about the iterator, worry about the code in the loop. What is it actually going to do with something that might be an `int` or might be a `string`? The answer to that question will help decide what type the iterator should return.

Comment: Since C++ doesn't support inspection, I thought the only way around it would be to query the iterator for the type.
Something like:
if (it.typeInt())
   int& i = *it; 
...

Its ugly as hell - that's why I was wondering if there was an elegant answer.

Comment: A good tip is: always make things simple. Make a class do one thing and each function do their own duty. And you seem try to make things complicated!

Comment: @billz - this was a question i came across, not something I'm inflicting on myself :)

Comment: @Raja: if that's what you want to do in the loop then use Boost.Variant. Another possibility would be to just handle strings in the loop, and convert the ints to string in the iterator. Another possibility would be for the code to first iterate over the strings and then iterate over the ints -- don't even try to treat them the same since they aren't.

Answer (score 1):

You could make your iterator's value type a variant like [Boost Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/variant.html).

Comment: Interesting - so you're saying I create a boost::variant iterator-visitor for this class?

Comment: Yes, that's a more general solution than say defining a tuple type and populating one or other of its fields.